# Cannot implicitly convert type with Enums

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, enums

Trying to troubleshoot this issue. Can't seem to assign one num to another even though they are practically identical.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Project.Models.Concern.YesNo' to
>   'Project.ViewModels.PatientConcernsViewModel.YesNo'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
public class Concern
{
    public int ConcernID { get; set; }
    public YesNo LifeExpectancy { get; set; }
    public YesNo CollateralHistoryAvailable { get; set; }

    public enum YesNo
    {
        Yes,
        No
    }
}

public class PatientConcernsViewModel
{
    public int ConcernID { get; set; }

    public YesNo LifeExpectancy { get; set; }        
    public YesNo CollateralHistoryAvailable { get; set; }

    public enum YesNo
    {
        Yes,
        No
    }
}

// FROM WITHIN MY CONTROLLER

var concern = concernRepository.Find(id);

// load related assessment data
var assessment = assessmentRepository.Find(AssessmentID);

PatientConcernsViewModel patientConcernsViewModel = new PatientConcernsViewModel();

// BOTH LINES BELOW GENERATE ERRORS            
patientConcernsViewModel.CollateralHistoryAvailable = concern.CollateralHistoryAvailable;
patientConcernsViewModel.LifeExpectancy = concern.LifeExpectancy;
```

Comment: Your `YesNo` enum is missing the value `FileNotFound`.

Comment: Why do you have a different `YesNo` enum for each class. Hell why do you have a `YesNo` enum? Why don't you use `bool`?

Comment: Having two identical classes doesn't not seem like good oo practice :)

Comment: Move the enum out of the class where both classes have access

Comment: @Harrison they both have access now. They are public nested enums.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your `enum` public without a class - then they can share it without having multiple definitions.

```
public enum YesNo
{
    Yes,
    No
}

public class Concern
{
    public int ConcernID { get; set; }
    public YesNo LifeExpectancy { get; set; }
    public YesNo CollateralHistoryAvailable { get; set; }
}

public class PatientConcernsViewModel
{
    public int ConcernID { get; set; }

    public YesNo LifeExpectancy { get; set; }        
    public YesNo CollateralHistoryAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Get rid of your `YesNo` enum and replace it with `System.Boolean`. Use system types when possible.

```
public class Concern
{
    public int ConcernID { get; set; }
    public bool LifeExpectancy { get; set; }
    public bool CollateralHistoryAvailable { get; set; }
}

public class PatientConcernsViewModel
{
    public int ConcernID { get; set; }

    public bool LifeExpectancy { get; set; }        
    public bool CollateralHistoryAvailable { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not scope the `YesNo` enum so that both are accessing the same object?

```
public enum YesNo
{
    Yes,
    No
}

public class Concern
{
    public int ConcernID { get; set; }
    public YesNo LifeExpectancy { get; set; }
    public YesNo CollateralHistoryAvailable { get; set; }
}

public class PatientConcernsViewModel
{
    public int ConcernID { get; set; }

    public YesNo LifeExpectancy { get; set; }        
    public YesNo CollateralHistoryAvailable { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 completely different enums, that happen to have the same items and the same last word in the fully qualified name.

As the error states you have `Project.Models.Concern.YesNo` and `Project.ViewModels.PatientConcernsViewModel.YesNo`

If you just place your enum somewhere else more appropriate then both classes can use it and you don't have 2 types.

Whilst the above answers your question as Aron states a bool would be better then a Yes/No enum for almost all purposes I can imagine.